# Empty list of listings

Tags: listings

How can I add my Listings to the `\lstlistoflistings`?!
Here is the Listing with example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\newtcblisting[auto counter,number within=section]{cpp}[2][]{
  title={Listing \thetcbcounter: #2},
  coltitle=black,
  colback=white,
  boxrule=0pt,
  arc=0pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
  top=0pt,
  bottom=0pt,
  colframe=white,
  listing only,
  left=15.5pt,
  enhanced,
  listing options={
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\color{red}\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{green}\ttfamily,
    breaklines=true,
    language=C++,
    showstringspaces=false,
    tabsize=2,
    numbers=left
  },
  overlay={
    \fill[gray!30] 
      ([xshift=-3pt]frame.south west)
      rectangle 
      ([xshift=11.5pt]frame.north west);
  }
}



\begin{document}

\lstlistoflistings

\begin{cpp}{iwconfig Aufruf}
root:~> iwconfig eth0
eth0      IEEE 802.11-bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Access Point: Not-Associated   Bit Rate=0 kb/s 
\end{cpp}

\end{document}
```

Using the code above for it only shows the `\listoflistings` Title and the listing itself but nothing inside the list of listings:

[image]

Comment: Please make a *full* (but minimal) example to reproduce the problem. Otherwise comments would have to start with the basic stuff like having listings, having `\lstlistoflistings`, usage of key `caption`, compiling the document at least twice, ...

Comment: Well, this is all I have. The call \lstlistoflistings is inside the \begin{document} part and compiled without any errors. except that no listing is there

Comment: Well, you can tell us is it like that, but how can we be sure. Please prepare a full example for *us* to reproduce *your* issue.

Comment: @Johannes_B  Ok, I copied my code into a plain tex file and added a listings example. I also added a picture of my output.

Comment: duplicate, with answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124192/89417 in particular the part about `addtolol`, lol being the list of listings.