# Using pgfkeys to create list of theorem environments defined by tcolorbox

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox, theorems, pgfkeys

I'm having trouble trying to get a list of various theorem environments I've created with `\newtcbtheorem`. After doing some digging, I found this answer from 2012 by @cmhughes: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87437. In this answer, he uses pgfkeys, specifically `/.code` to add the entry to a new table of contents file. It works perfectly when I use it, however `\tcbmaketheorem` is deprecated and I wanted to convert it to `\newtcbtheorem` so that it can use the new standard and also because it allows for me to call a theorem environment without a number. However, I could not figure out how to adjust the pgfkeys and all the documentation online was difficult to understand. Here is a MWE that returns:

```
Runaway argument?
\fi \pgfkeys@parse title={\tcb@theo@title {Theorem}{\thetcbcounter }{\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \pgfkeys@code.
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[]{calc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[theorems]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{noparskip}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\listtheoremname{List of Theorems}
\newcommand\listoftheorems{%
  \section*{\listtheoremname}\@starttoc{thm}}
\tcbset{
  thmbox/.code args={#1#2#3#4}{%
  \refstepcounter{#2}\label{#4}%
   \addcontentsline{defs}{subsection}{\protect\numberline{\csname the#2\endcsname} #3}, % new bit
  \pgfkeysalso{title={\setlength{\hangindent}{\widthof{#1~\csname the#2\endcsname:\ }}\hangafter=1 \mbox{#1~\csname the#2\endcsname:\ }#3}}}}
\makeatother
% moved new theorem declaration to the preamble
\newcounter{mytheorem}[section]
\def\themytheorem{\thesection.\arabic{mytheorem}}

\newtcbtheorem[use counter=mytheorem]{theo}{Theorem}{thmbox}{theorem}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents{}
\listoftheorems % new bit
\pagebreak{}
\section{Theorems}


\begin{theo}{Summation of Numbers}{summation}

  For all natural number $n$ it holds:\\[2mm]
  $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.
\end{theo}

We have given Theorem \ref{theorem:summation} on page \pageref{theorem:summation}.

\pagebreak{}

\end{document}
```

And here is my log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./master.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15>
L3 programming layer <2021-11-12>
($HOME/texmf/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
($HOME/texmf/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
($HOME/texmf/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
($HOME/texmf/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
($HOME/texmf/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.tex))
($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def)
($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)))
($HOME/texmf/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
($HOME/texmf/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
($HOME/texmf/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
($HOME/texmf/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
($HOME/texmf/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
($HOME/texmf/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
($HOME/texmf/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def)))
($HOME/texmf/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex))
($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.def
($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def)))
($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex)
($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex))
($HOME/texmf/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
($HOME/texmf/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg))
($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex)
($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex)
($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code
.tex)
($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex)
($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.te
x) ($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex)
($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex)
($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex)
($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetics
.code.tex))) ($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex)
) ($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex)
($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex)
($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex
) ($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.tex)
($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex)
($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex)

($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.code.t
ex) ($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex)
($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex)
($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.code.te
x) ($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex)
($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex)
($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex
($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex))
($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex)
($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code.tex)
 ($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex)
($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.tex)))
($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex)
($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex)
($HOME/texmf/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty)
($HOME/texmf/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty))
($HOME/texmf/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
($HOME/texmf/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex))
($HOME/texmf/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)))
($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex
($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.code.te
x) ($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex)
($HOME/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrary
topaths.code.tex))) ($HOME/texmf/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)
($HOME/texmf/tex/latex/float/float.sty)
($HOME/texmf/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.sty
($HOME/texmf/tex/latex/tools/verbatim.sty)
($HOME/texmf/tex/latex/environ/environ.sty
($HOME/texmf/tex/latex/trimspaces/trimspaces.sty))
($HOME/texmf/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
($HOME/texmf/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcbtheorems.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbtheorems.code.tex' version '4.42'
($HOME/texmf/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
($HOME/texmf/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
($HOME/texmf/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
($HOME/texmf/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
($HOME/texmf/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))))
($HOME/texmf/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def) (./master.aux)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) ($HOME/texmf/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty)
($HOME/texmf/tex/latex/grfext/grfext.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty))
($HOME/texmf/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty))
($HOME/texmf/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg)) (./master.toc)
(./master.thm) [1{$HOME/.texlive/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pd
ftex.map}])
Runaway argument?
\fi \pgfkeys@parse title={\tcb@theo@title {Theorem}{\thetcbcounter }{\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \pgfkeys@code.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> ./master.tex
                
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on master.log.
```

Any ideas on how to solve this? I tried messing around with it while reading the documentation of pgfkeys but I seemed to only make it worse. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check the answer next to the one you linked, and posted by author of `tcolorbox`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124192.

Answer (score 1):

**Remark:** My answer is almost identical to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124192), which was posted by [Thomas F. Sturm](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/30617/thomas-f-sturm), the author of `tcolorbox`, 7 years ago.

Just use `add to list={thm}{subsection}`:

```tex
\newtcbtheorem[use counter=mytheorem]{theo}{Theorem}
  {add to list={thm}{subsection}}{theorem}
```

Option `add to list` was added in `tcolorbox` v2.40 (2013/07/15) (see its [changelog](https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/blob/11e2ba1bfe76ab1efb7bef77d46b0d9a109437f6/doc/latex/tcolorbox/CHANGES.md?plain=1#L380)), hence is not available when the linked question was asked in 2012 Dec.

Full example

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[]{calc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[theorems]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{noparskip}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\listtheoremname{List of Theorems}
\newcommand\listoftheorems{%
  \section*{\listtheoremname}\@starttoc{thm}}
\makeatother

% moved new theorem declaration to the preamble
\newcounter{mytheorem}[section]
\def\themytheorem{\thesection.\arabic{mytheorem}}

\newtcbtheorem[use counter=mytheorem]{theo}{Theorem}{add to list={thm}{subsection}}{theorem}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoftheorems % new bit
\pagebreak

\section{Theorems}

\begin{theo}{Summation of Numbers}{summation}
  For all natural number $n$ it holds:\\[2mm]
  $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.
\end{theo}

We have given Theorem \ref{theorem:summation} on page \pageref{theorem:summation}.

\end{document}
```

[image]